# Using multiple row results on a formula, based by group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to use the results from a multiple rows on a formula, divided by each group.

I have the followin formula:

```
result = (1st vfg ) / (1 + (1st vfg / 2nd vfg) + (1st vfg / 3rd vfg) + ... + (1st vfg / *nth* vfg) )
```

*vfg = value from group*

For example, the table bellow:

```
Group | Value
---------------
  1   |  1000
  1   |  280
  1   |  280
  2   |  1000
```

Note: I guarantee that there will be no 0 (zero) or NULLs in the value for the first table

Should give me the following result:

```
Group | Result
---------------
  1   |  122.85
  2   |  1000     -> If there is only one value on the group, the result will be the value itself
```

Comment: Do you need it as a single SELECT statement? Or with use of variables? For sure you can make it in steps: 1. Grab the 1st value for group. 2. Compute for each row `1st vfg / nth vfg 3`. Compute for each group `1st vfg / (sum of 1st vfg / nth vfg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a column that indicates the row order within a group (timestamps, the sequence number, identity column, etc.). Rows in a database table have no implicit order. Once you have that, you can use a CTE and window functions to solve the problem:

```
;WITH
    cte AS
    (
        SELECT      [Group]
                ,   [Value]
                ,   FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY RowOrder)              AS FirstValue
                ,   FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY RowOrder) / [Value]    AS Subtotal
        FROM        MyTable
    )

SELECT      [Group]
        ,   AVG(FirstValue) / SUM(Subtotal)     AS Result
FROM        cte
GROUP BY    [Group]
```